# dbplyr group by dynamic variable names

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

How can I group using a dynamic variable(s) name(s) ?

My example : Try to group on `Species` column knowing it is in the `grouping_variable` var ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)

# My table
iris_table <- tbl(src = my_db_conn, in_schema(schema = "my_schema", table = "iris_table"))

# The grouping variable
grouping_variable <- "Species"

# My tries
iris_table %>%
  group_by(across(any_of(grouping_variable))) %>%
  summarise(sum_petal_length = sum(Petal.Length))
### ==> returns error

iris_table %>%
  group_by(!!!grouping_variable) %>%
  summarise(sum_petal_length = sum(Petal.Length))
### ==> returns grouping by the character "Species"
```

My `sessionInfo()` :

```
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DBI_1.1.0               dbplyr_1.4.4            dplyr_1.0.0             lubridate_1.7.9        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5          rstudioapi_0.11     magrittr_1.5        hms_0.5.3           odbc_1.3.0          tidyselect_1.1.0   
 [7] bit_1.1-15.2        R6_2.4.1            rlang_0.4.7         fansi_0.4.1         blob_1.2.1          tools_3.6.2        
[13] utf8_1.1.4          cli_2.0.2           ellipsis_0.3.1      readxl_1.3.1        bit64_0.9-7.1       assertthat_0.2.1   
[19] tibble_3.0.3        lifecycle_0.2.0     crayon_1.3.4        zip_2.0.4           purrr_0.3.4         tidyr_1.1.0        
[25] vctrs_0.3.2         glue_1.4.1          openxlsx_4.1.5      stringi_1.4.6       cellranger_1.1.0    compiler_3.6.2     
[31] pillar_1.4.6        generics_0.0.2      pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two potential approaches.

**(1)** Most similar to the approach you are already using, we first have to tell R that the character string should be treated as symbolic:

```r
iris_table %>%
  group_by(!!!syms(grouping_variable)) %>%
  summarise(sum_petal_length = sum(Petal.Length))
```

Note the `syms` before the `!!!`. This approach uses some features of the rlang package that can be useful in other contexts. However, it is no longer the recommended approach for programming with dplyr.

**(2)** The recommended approach for doing this kind of [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) is:

```r
iris_table %>%
  group_by(.data[[grouping_variable]]) %>%
  summarise(sum_petal_length = sum(Petal.Length))
```

Both of these approaches will give you the correct SQL translation when working with dbplyr:

```r
data(iris)
iris_table = tbl_lazy(iris, con = simulate_mssql())
# The grouping variable
grouping_variable <- "Species"

# approach 1
iris_table %>%
  group_by(!!!syms(grouping_variable)) %>%
  summarise(sum_petal_length = sum(Petal.Length))
# translation from approach 1
# <SQL>
# SELECT `Species`, SUM(`Petal.Length`) AS `sum_petal_length`
# FROM `df`
# GROUP BY `Species`

# approach 2
iris_table %>%
  group_by(.data[[grouping_variable]]) %>%
  summarise(sum_petal_length = sum(Petal.Length))
# translation from approach 2
# <SQL>
# SELECT `Species`, SUM(`Petal.Length`) AS `sum_petal_length`
# FROM `df`
# GROUP BY `Species`
```

Comment: I'll go for the 1st approach because I didn't manage to get it work with `.data[[grouping_variable]]` when I have more than 1 element. But `!!!syms(grouping_variable)` works with more than one element. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So, for dplyr version 1.0.3 it is working perfectly fine.

```r
grouping_variable <- "Species"

data("iris")
iris_table <- as_tibble(iris) %>%
  group_by(across(any_of(grouping_variable))) %>%
  summarise(sum_petal_length = sum(Petal.Length))

> iris_table
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    sum_petal_length
* <fct>                 <dbl>
1 setosa                 73.1
2 versicolor            213  
3 virginica             278. 

packageVersion("dplyr")
#> [1] '1.0.3'
```

As far as I remember, in older dplyr versions `grouping_variable <- sym("Species")` should do the trick.

Comment: That this works in local dplyr does not guarantee that it will work in dbplyr. dbplyr is a technology for working with remote databases.

Comment: @Simon.S.A. totally right. I'm not sure `across` & `any_of` works with `dbplyr`